# How to resize an image during uploading in mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql, image, resize

I have the following code for uploading the image in database.

```
<html>
<head><title>File Insert</title></head>
<body>
<h3>Please Choose a File and click Submit</h3>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action=
"<?php echo $_SERVER['server address']; ?>" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="10000000" />
<input name="userfile" type="file" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<?php

// check if a file was submitted
if(!isset($_FILES['userfile']))
{
    echo '<p>Please select a file</p>';
}
else
{
    try {
    $msg= upload();  //this will upload your image
    echo $msg;  //Message showing success or failure.
    }
    catch(Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    echo 'Sorry, could not upload file';
    }
}

// the upload function

function upload() {
    $host="your_hostname";
    $user="your_databaseuser";
    $pass="your_database_password";
    $db="database_name_to_use";
    $maxsize = 10000000; //set to approx 10 MB

    //check associated error code
    if($_FILES['userfile']['error']==UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {

        //check whether file is uploaded with HTTP POST
        if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'])) {    

            //checks size of uploaded image on server side
            if( $_FILES['userfile']['size'] < $maxsize) {  

               //checks whether uploaded file is of image type
              if(strpos(mime_content_type($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']),"image")===0) {
              //   $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
              //  if(strpos(finfo_file($finfo, $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']),"image")===0) {    

                    // prepare the image for insertion
                    $imgData =addslashes (file_get_contents($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']));

                    // put the image in the db...
                    // database connection
                    mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) OR DIE (mysql_error());

                    // select the db
                    mysql_select_db ($db) OR DIE ("Unable to select db".mysql_error());

                    // our sql query
                    $sql = "INSERT INTO test_image
                    (image, name)
                    VALUES
                    ('{$imgData}', '{$_FILES['userfile']['name']}');";

                    // insert the image
                    mysql_query($sql) or die("Error in Query: " . mysql_error());
                    $msg='<p>Image successfully saved in database with id ='. mysql_insert_id().' </p>';
                }
                else
                    $msg="<p>Uploaded file is not an image.</p>";
            }
             else {
                // if the file is not less than the maximum allowed, print an error
                $msg='<div>File exceeds the Maximum File limit</div>
                <div>Maximum File limit is '.$maxsize.' bytes</div>
                <div>File '.$_FILES['userfile']['name'].' is '.$_FILES['userfile']['size'].
                ' bytes</div><hr />';
                }
        }
        else
            $msg="File not uploaded successfully.";

    }
    else {
        $msg= file_upload_error_message($_FILES['userfile']['error']);
    }
    return $msg;
}

// Function to return error message based on error code

function file_upload_error_message($error_code) {
    switch ($error_code) {
        case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE:
            return 'The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini';
        case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE:
            return 'The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form';
        case UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL:
            return 'The uploaded file was only partially uploaded';
        case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE:
            return 'No file was uploaded';
        case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR:
            return 'Missing a temporary folder';
        case UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE:
            return 'Failed to write file to disk';
        case UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION:
            return 'File upload stopped by extension';
        default:
            return 'Unknown upload error';
    }
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

My problem is that this code is saving the full size of image.I want to resize the image before uploading to the database.How can i do that???

Comment: You are inserting the image data in the database? That's is a BAD choice.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to create bitmap from file by [imagecreatefromjpeg($string path to file)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php), than empty bitmap by [ImageCreateTrueColor($tmbWs,$tmbHs);](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatetruecolor.php), after this use [ImageCopyResampled()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php)

Answer (score 0):

In modern browsers you can use the File API, and html5 canvas.

```
var file = YOUR_FILE,
fileType = file.type,
reader = new FileReader();

reader.onloadend = function() {
var image = new Image();
image.src = reader.result;

image.onload = function() {

    imageWidth = image.width,
    imageHeight = image.height;

    //calculate new width and height however you want
    // var newWidth, newHeight;
    // ...

    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = newWidth;
    canvas.height = newHeight;

    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);

    // get the resized file
    var finalFile = canvas.toDataURL(fileType);
  }
}

reader.readAsDataURL(file);
```

Comment: By this you can't resize image before uploading, can you?

Comment: Yes you can, this uses new html5 to resize BEFORE actually uploading!

Comment: You should, it's the future! ;)

Comment: Hey thanks,But I am not able get how to link my code to your code to resize the image?

Comment: My code is javascript, it should work with your html upload form.